# Nettoiement et nettoyage

Tags: usage, histoire, synonymes

Comment peut-on expliquer le décalage entre les fréquences d'usage des mots

> nettoiement et nettoyage

comme ce [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nettoiement%2Cnettoyage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnettoiement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnettoyage%3B%2Cc0) le vérifie ?

Selon https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nettoiement

> A. − Action de nettoyer; synon. peu usité de nettoyage.La substance la
>   plus fréquemment utilisée pour l'injection des bois est la créosote
>   qui, comme la plupart des huiles lourdes n'est pas délavée par le
>   nettoiement à grande eau et les pluies (Bourde,Trav. publ.,1929,
>   p.93).
>
> B. − Ensemble des opérations, des mesures ayant pour but de nettoyer.
>   Service du nettoiement de la ville de Paris. Le nettoiement des rues;
>   le nettoiement d'un égout (Ac. 1935)

Pourquoi doit-on dire, par exemple

> nettoiement d'un port et nettoyage d'une maison

?

Nettoiement signifie-t-il nettoyer d'une façon plus générale ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On peut trouver d'autres exemples de paires de dérivés de ce style. Contrairement à ***nettoyage - nettoiement*** qui sont assez proches, beaucoup ne sont pas ou quasiment pas interchangeables. Par exemple :

> Réglage - Règlement
>
> Blanchissage - Blanchiment
>
> Lavage - Lavement
>
> Battage - Battement
>
> Emballage - Emballement

Le suffixe **-age** indique toujours l'action, l'exécution effective.

Le suffixe **-ment** peut, lui, indiquer le résultat obtenu, une spécialisation, une description de la méthode ou une ensemble d'opérations dans le cas de *nettoiement*.

Le *nettoiement d'un port* est souvent plus global que le *nettoyage d'un port*, mais les deux se recouvrent partiellement.

Le *nettoiement* pourra décrire un ensemble de nettoyages particuliers (nettoyage du fond en retirant les object immergés, nettoyage de l'eau en retirant les objets flottants ou les hydrocarbures, nettoyage des quais, etc.)

On utilisera plutôt *nettoiement*, plus "noble", pour qualifier le service ou la société chargée de l'organisation et de l'exécution du nettoyage.

Pour une maison individuelle, *nettoyage* est plus courant car il n'y a pas de service chargé d'organiser le nettoyage et peu de variété dans les opérations.