# Le sens d' « écoblanchiment » s'appuie-t-il vraiment sur l' « action de donner une existence légale... » etc. ?

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, suffixes

Dans un titre on trouve « *À l'ONU, les jeunes dénoncent l’écoblanchiment* » ([lapresse.ca](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/environnement/201909/21/01-5242262-a-lonu-les-jeunes-denoncent-lecoblanchiment.php)) et je ne connaissais pas ce terme (ni le sens de [*greenwashing*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/greenwashing) vraiment d'ailleurs) et je ne l'ai pas spontanément compris. La définition réfère à une « opération de relations publiques menée par une organisation, une entreprise pour masquer ses activités polluantes et tenter de présenter un caractère écoresponsable » ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8365406)) ou à l' « attribution abusive de qualités écologiques à un produit, à un service ou à une organisation » ([Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=greenwashing&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) au [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26539960), principalement sous le vocable *verdissement d'image*).

Le GDT indique que "*blanchiment* est employé ici par extension du sens d'« action de donner une existence légale à quelque chose dont l'origine est illicite »", non sans rappeler l'expression familière et au figuré ([Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9B1314)), [*blanchiment d'argent*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanchiment_d%27argent) [*money laundering*]. Mais *donner une existence légale* cadre mal il me semble avec le ce dont il est question avec l'*écoblanchiment* : en fait je ne vois pas le lien du tout. Enfin j'ai lu une [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39784) sur la suffixation *-age/ment*.

- Pourquoi une *opération de relation publique* ou une *représentation
  abusive* s'apparentent-elles à l'*action de donner une existence
  légale*... le GDT fait-il fausse route ; en d'autres termes y a-t-il adéquation entre ce que l'on associe normalement au *blanchiment* (et plus généralement à la suffixation) et ce dont il est question ; le *blanchiment d'argent* ne distrait-il pas de ce dont il est question ici ?
- Pourquoi *écoblanchissage* aurait-il été meilleur ou non ?
- Remettrait-on en question le choix du substantif dans *écoblanchiment*
  quand on le compare à *verdissage d'image* pour traduire
  *greenwashing* ?

Answer (score 1):

*Ecoblanchiment* semble être une tentative de traduction littérale de *greenwashing*.

1. Le préfixe *éco-* fait ici implicitement référence à écologie, mais il n'y a aucun moyen de déterminer (à part connaître le mot anglais) s'il ne viendrait pas de *économie* par exemple.
2. Le terme *blanchiment*, plutôt que *blanchissage*, a certainement été choisi pour mettre l'accent sur le caractère douteux de l'opération, en référence au blanchiment d'argent sale.

Si j'avais à traduire *greenwashing* je porterais plutôt ma réflexion vers une fine couche de peinture verte.

Comment: Je sais pas si ça peut être l'équivalent de _a [washing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/washing) of green_. Perso. je trouve que le caractère douteux c'est vraiment flou et ténu, _blanchir de l'argent_ implique plusieurs actions qui mènent essentiellement en la création d'écritures comptables/bancaires ou d'instruments représentants des titres etc. à partir d'argent comptant obtenu lors de la vente de stupéfiants par exemple etc. D'accord on trouve les représentations douteuses, voire fausses, mais je trouve qu'il faut vraiment (trop?) généraliser pour en arriver à y voir le lien avec l'$.